# r subset by multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, multiple-columns

I am bit confused about the logic to subset the dataset based on specific conditions for multiple columns.

For example if this is my dataset

```
ID   Sex Age  Score
1    M   4.2  19
1    M   4.8  21
2    F   6.1  23
2    F   6.7  45
3    F   9.4  39
4    M   8    33
5    M   10   56
```

The acceptable range of Score for `Gender=Male` between `Age(between, 6 to 11)` is `Score(between, 34 to 100)` .

The final dataset would be, without ID 4

```
ID   Sex Age  Score
1    M   4.2  19
1    M   4.8  21
2    F   6.1  23
2    F   6.7  45
3    F   9.4  39
5    M   10   56
```

I tried this approach,

```
Df0 <- subset( Df0, (between(Age, 6,11)&
                     Sex == "M"&
                     between(Score, 34, 100))
```

And this did not work. Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a typo, we are missing `)` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your explanation correctly along with the expected output shown you are looking for something like this -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(ifelse(Sex == 'M' & between(Age, 6,11), 
          between(Score, 34, 100), TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup

#     ID Sex     Age Score
#  <int> <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1     1 M       4.2    19
#2     1 M       4.8    21
#3     2 F       6.1    23
#4     2 F       6.7    45
#5     3 F       9.4    39
#6     5 M      10      56
```

`between(Score, 34, 100)` is only checked when the `Sex` is `'M'` and `Age` is between 6 and 11.

Comment: this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Classical

```
subset(dat, Age > 6 & Age < 11 & Sex == 'M' & Score > 34 & Score < 100)
#   ID Sex Age Score
# 7  5   M  10    56
```

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
subset(dat, between(Age, 6, 11)  & Sex == 'M' & between(Score, 34, 100))
#   ID Sex Age Score
# 7  5   M  10    56
```

or

```
subset(dat, Age %between% c(6, 11) & Sex == 'M' & Score %between% c(34, 100))
#   ID Sex Age Score
# 7  5   M  10    56
```

or fully `data.table`

```
setDT(df)[Sex == "M" & between(Age, 6, 11) & between(Score, 34, 100)]
#    ID Sex Age Score
# 1:  5   M  10    56
```

Comment: Please do not rush with answer, it is a simple typo. If it wasn't a typo, then it is 100% dupe.

Comment: We can use `setDT(df)[Sex == "M" & between(Age, 6, 11) & between(Score, 34, 100)]` when using `data.table` :)

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Yes, I was afraid of something like that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
Df0 %>% 
    filter(Sex == 'M', between(Age, 6,11), between(Score, 34,100))
```

Comment: You can use on only one filter, `dplyr::filter(Sex == 'M', between(Age, 6,11), between(Score, 34,100))`